# Manually validate PowerShell parameters

Tags: powershell

I am looking for a way to manually validate the parameters passed to the script.

I tried to iterate through the list of all the parameters using $PSBoundParameters (built-in variable) but I am not getting any results using the same.

For some reason (they way we have to implement the script) I can't use the PowerShell's built-in way of validation. I have to manually validate all the parameters.

```
[CmdletBinding()]
Param
(
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$False,ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$true)]
    [string]$AzureUserName,

    [Parameter(Mandatory=$False,ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$true)]
    [string]$AzurePassword,

    [Parameter(Mandatory=$False,ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$true)]
    [string]$AzureSubscriptionID,

    [Parameter(Mandatory=$False,ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$true)]
    [string]$Location,

    [Parameter(Mandatory=$False,ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$true)]
    [String]$ResourceGroupName,

    [Parameter(Mandatory=$False,ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$true)]
    [String]$DeploymentName,

    [Parameter(Mandatory=$False,ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$true)]
    [String]$TemplateJSONPath,

    [Parameter(Mandatory=$False,ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$true)]
    [String]$ParameterJSONPath,

    [Parameter(Mandatory=$False,ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$true)]
    [String]$VNetName,

    [Parameter(Mandatory=$False,ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$true,HelpMessage="Example: 10.0.0.0/16")]
    [String]$vnetAddressPrefix,

    [Parameter(Mandatory=$False,ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$true,HelpMessage="Example: 10.0.0.0/16")]
    [String]$subnet1Prefix,

    [Parameter(Mandatory=$False,ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$true,HelpMessage="Example: 10.0.0.0/16")]
    [String]$subnet2Prefix,

    [Parameter(Mandatory=$False,ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$true,HelpMessage="Example: 10.0.0.0/16")]
    [String]$GatewayPrefix
)

Begin
{
}

Process
{
    $paramList = $PSBoundParameters.Values
    $i=1
    Write-Host "Found $($paramList.Count) parameters"
    ForEach($Parameter In $paramList)
    {
        Write-Host "Param $i value: $Parameter"
        $i++
    }
}
```

I am getting the results as:

```
Found 0 parameters
```

Comment: Why you don't want to use the built-in way? What do you need to validate?

Comment: Because we have to call this script through some web based code in backend. If there is any parameter which is set to Mandatory and don't get value for some reason, then the script will prompt for the value for that parameter and will wait there and the thread will get stuck until someone kills the thread.

Comment: okay, that make sense.

Comment: ran your code and I get `Found 4 parameters
Param 1 value: fsa` etc.

Comment: I agree, to it when you pass the value.. But, when you don't pass the value for a parameter it will not show that parameter.

Comment: I am doing it manually for one of the scripts like given in this link: [PowerShell Script for manually validating parameters](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0BwjjITNwzu3INERrdkdMQ1FjVDA). However, I want find a better way of doing this as other scripts have too many parameters to validate to use this way.

Comment: The sitting there and waiting for a parameter only applies to interactive sessions. For example, if  I start, PowerShell with `PowerShell -NonInteractive` and type `Install-module` instead of prompting for a module name, I get the following error `Install-Module : Cannot process command because of one or more missing mandatory parameters: Name.`

Comment: I agree with you @TravisPlunk. However, in our case we expect every kind of output converted to JSON format. Thus for every error or validation issue we are returning JSON output which our automation engine can interpret. For now I am doing it manually as mentioned in the second comment (link) above. However I have to do this for many other scripts which may have even larger number of parameters to be validated and there is a chance that i may miss one if I don't use a better way.

Comment: BTW, @TravisPlunk I didn't know about -NonInteractive option. Thanks for that piece of info. it might be useful in some other case.